# Prevent wrong imports in Netbeans

Tags: codenameone

Sometimes I don't notice that Netbeans imports the wrong packages inside a Codename One project. It causes me to waste time until I notice a such sneaky mistake. *This happens me a lot of times, especially when I'm a bit tired of coding...*

Is there any way to force Netbeans to don't propose and don't do any automatic import from packages different from the ones provided by Codename One and created by me inside my project?

Of course, if it's possible, it should be applied only to Codename One projects. I have also a Spring Boot project that, of course, needs different imports.

Currently I'm using Netbeans 10 with Java 8. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: You can only exclude packages to be excluded from import globally, not on a per-project basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is, it's theoretically possible but really hard. It would open the door for far worse problems.

The last time we checked about that it was only possible in two ways:

- If we copied the entire Java module and built on top of that
- If we built Codename One as a JDK

Both options are a bit problematic. The former would mean we would need to maintain the full Java package code and update it with changes to the IDE. We don't want to do that.

The latter would also be problematic since we don't support any officially supported subset of a JDK. It would also break the existing project structure and make things like running the project much harder.